# Error showing while trying to install tensorflow_decision_forests in python

Tags: python

I am trying to install Tensorflow Decision Forests in Spyder 3.8 using the following command: `pip install tensorflow_decision_forests`. It shows the following error:

```
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow_decision_forests
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow_decision_forests
```

Am I using the wrong Anaconda version or am I missing something in between? Kindly help me in this.

Thanks In advance!

Answer (score 0):

*Update February 2023*: Tensorflow Decision Forests is now [available](https://pypi.org/project/tensorflow-decision-forests/#files) on MacOS (and has been so for the last few months).

If you have Mac or Windows, this library is still not available. You can check out the information in [this official website](https://www.tensorflow.org/decision_forests):

> Unfortunately TF-DF is not yet available for [Mac (#16)](https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests/issues/16) or [Windows (#3)](https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests/issues/3), we are working on it.

Comment: So, is it available in Linux?

Comment: Seems like it should, you can checkout the installation steps [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/decision-forests/blob/main/documentation/installation.md#installation-with-pip). Docs recommend using `pip3 install tensorflow_decision_forests --upgrade`